# MongoDB aggregate - get N random documents on document's count condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

What I am trying to achieve is to make `$limit` a bit smarter, as I need to limit my aggregation to evenly distributed N documents (not just the first N documents). Is it doable?

My first guess is to use `$sample` if count>N. Pseudocode for N = 500:

```
{
   $match: { some_dummy_initial_condition },
},
{ // Conditional step:
  IF $count > 500 THEN $sample: { 500 }
}
```

Edit: If there is no way to skip any pipeline stage then maybe there is a way to use `$limit` that will uniformly distribute my documents (like skipping every nth document, so I would not exceed my upper N limit)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to skip any pipeline stage, you can try one kind of hack, this is not accurate in memory or speed when lots of data collection,

- `$facet` to create 2 separate data array, one `data` for all documents, second `sample` for sample 500 documents
- `$project` to check if size of data is greater than 500 then return sample array to data otherwise return data array
- `$unwind` deconstruct data array
- `$replaceWith` to replace data object in root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { some_dummy_initial_condition } },
  {
    $facet: {
      data: [],
      sample: [ { $sample: { size: 500 } } ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $cond: [
          { $gt: [{ $size: "$data" }, 500] },
          "$sample",
          "$data"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$data" },
  { $replaceWith: "$data" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cxmqKV7rW6G)

Comment: Thank you, indeed - this is still a heavyweight operation for my database. If there is no way to skip any pipeline stage then maybe there is a way to $limit with uniformly distributed documents (like taking nth document so I would not exceed my N limit)?

Comment: how $limit knows that it has greater than 500 documents, i am not getting exactly your comment, you need to put pagination using $limit and $skip?

Comment: Updated my original question, to explain better what I am trying to achieve. Sorry for misunderstanding!